# Modifying MySQL Query for WpDataTables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am building a table in WpDataTables that involves two custom post types: 'applicants' and 'reviews'. I am trying to create a table that shows all of the applicants that have either been reviewed by the current user (reviewer) who is viewing the WpDataTable. Each applicant can have one or more reviews.

This query runs exactly like I want it to in MySQL, however, WpDataTables does not like it for some reason. I believe it is because of the subquery.

```
SELECT a.ID, r.post_title, a.post_title, a.guid, r.post_type, a.post_type, r.post_author,
b.meta_value review_app_score,
c.meta_value review_app_comment
FROM (SELECT * FROM `wppm_2_posts` WHERE post_author = 1 AND post_type = 'reviews' AND post_status = 'publish') as r
RIGHT JOIN `wppm_2_posts`as a ON r.post_title = a.ID
LEFT JOIN `wppm_2_postmeta` b ON r.ID = b.post_id AND b.meta_key='review_app_score'
LEFT JOIN `wppm_2_postmeta` c ON r.ID = c.post_id AND c.meta_key='review_app_comment'
WHERE a.post_type = 'applicants'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

Here is what the MySQL results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzvHt.png

This is exactly what I am needing, except I need it to work in WpDataTables.

The reason is that I am looking to take advantage of their dynamic placeholder (%CURRENT_USER_ID%) instead of the '1' in the subquery above for post_author. 
Such as:

```
(SELECT * FROM `wppm_2_posts` WHERE post_author = %CURRENT_USER_ID% AND post_type = 'reviews' AND post_status = 'publish')
```

Is there another way I could write this without using a subquery? Or there is another way to build this without needing the dynamic placeholder such as PHP?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mixing `left join`s and `right join`s makes a query really hard to understand.

Comment: @gordonLinoff I can understand that. Unfortunately, how I've built the query is the best that I could do with the knowledge that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the professional way (AKA it wasn't me) of writing the query. Not sure if it will help anyone else but hopefully it will.

```
SELECT 
    APPLICANTS.ID AS applicants_id
    ,APPLICANTS.post_title AS applicants_post_title
    ,APPLICANTS.guid AS applicants_guid
    ,APPLICANTS.post_type AS applicants_post_type
    ,REVIEWS.post_author AS reviews_author_id
    ,REVIEWS.post_type AS reviews_post_type
    ,REVIEWS.post_title AS reviews_post_title
    ,R_APP_SCORES.meta_value AS review_app_score
    ,R_APP_COMMENTS.meta_value AS review_app_comment
FROM 
    `%WPDB%posts` AS APPLICANTS 
    LEFT JOIN
    `%WPDB%posts` AS REVIEWS ON
        (REVIEWS.post_author = %CURRENT_USER_ID%) AND     
        (REVIEWS.post_title = APPLICANTS.ID) AND 
        (REVIEWS.post_type = 'reviews') AND 
        (REVIEWS.post_status = 'publish')
    LEFT JOIN 
    `%WPDB%postmeta` R_APP_SCORES ON
        (R_APP_SCORES.post_id = REVIEWS.ID) AND 
        (R_APP_SCORES.meta_key = 'review_app_score')
    LEFT JOIN 
    `%WPDB%postmeta` R_APP_COMMENTS ON 
        (R_APP_COMMENTS.post_id = REVIEWS.ID) AND
        (R_APP_COMMENTS.meta_key = 'review_app_comment')
WHERE 
    (APPLICANTS.post_type = 'applicants') AND
    (APPLICANTS.post_status = 'publish')
```